# Data Visualisation Algorithm Books

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

I am looking to buy a good book on data visualisation and would love to here your recommendations. My background is mathematical and I am currently working on a data analysis tool for my employer. The two books that have intrigued me so far are

The Visual Display of Quantitative Information by Tufte

Interactive Data Visualization: Foundations, Techniques, and Applications by Ward

I'm more interested in algorithms and efficient ways to analyse the data. I'd like a book that could explain how to make graphs similar to the ones on this website.

http://www.randelshofer.ch/treeviz/

Comment: this should probably be a community wiki

Comment: This post should help: [Recommended Data Visualisation Books?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1457003/404469)

Answer (score 0):

The list post suggested by *@gary comtois* is great, but if you are looking for algorithms I would suggest looking at:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514556

It assumes programming knowledge but isn't the most challenging of books. However it covers  plotting graphs, treemaps and other things.

The bibliography is also quite good.

Hope it helps.

David